# How to Add a PDF Document to a UIWebView using ASIHTTP

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview, asihttprequest

I have the following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_TO_DOWNLOAD];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
```

When this is completed I want to view the URL (PDF) downloaded inside my `UIWebView`. I create a `UIWebView` programatically however I can't figure out a way to `loadRequest` my actual ASIHTTP Request.

Answer (score 0):

you could display a pdf in your device by two way.

first by passing the url to UIWebView directly, in this case you do'nt require to download pdf file

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 420)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

And the second way , you  first need to download  (As you  are doing) then get the path of pdf file from your application bundle,

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *pdfpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfpath ];
NSURLRequest *pdfRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL ];
[webView loadRequest:pdfRequest];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: how can i use ASIHTTP though with the any of these examples?

Comment: @Alx: Once you download the document from web by using the ASIHTTP , you could use the second way (mentioned above) to show the document in UIWebView  thanks ...